# Need to do sorting of ArrayList<Object> for a particular field?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I need to sort my ArrayList according to date which is in Student object... If the date(joining date) is same then i need to sort it according to ID... how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in two common ways.

**The easy way**

1) Having the Student provide an implementation of Comparable, which ultimately will defer to the Date. This is a very simple operation, but it is a bit of a hack.

**The maintainable way**

2) Alternatively,the Collections.sort method takes a Comparator as input - and you can easily write a custom comparator that implements the comparison necessary for sorting, by casting the inputs into Student classes, and directly returning the data comparison.

The second solution is more modular and maintainable, unless comparison by date is s fundamental , central aspect of your application.

Comment: And as of Java 5, casting is mosttimes not necessary anymore inside the Comparator. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface in your Student class. Then use
 `Collections.sort(list);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something as follows:

Either make the class implement `Comparable`:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    private Date joinDate;
    private String id;

    //...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        int result = joinDate.compareTo(o.joinDate);
        if(result != 0) {
            return result;
        }
        return id.compareTo(o.id);
    }    
}
```

Or use a `Comparator`:

```
Comparator<Student> comparator = new Comparator<Student>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        int result = o1.getJoinDate().compareTo(o2.getJoinDate());
        if (result != 0) {
            return result;
        }
        return o1.getId().compareTo(o1.getId());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Collections` class has a sort method that takes a `Comparator` as an argument:

```
List<Student> students;

/* ...students list instantiated and populated somewhere along here... */

Collections.sort(students, new Comparator<Student>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Student student1, Student student2) {
        return student1.joinDate().compareTo(student2.joinDate());
    }
});
```

I should add that, if your list is indeed declared as `Object` generic, you're going to have to do a lot of casting. That list should be declared generic to `Student` and you should have other lists of non-student objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this one of two ways:

1) Implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface on your object and call `Collections.sort(yourList);'.

Or

2) Implement the [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface a new class (let's pretend you call that class `StudentDateComparator`.  Then you can call Collections.sort(yourList, new StudentDateComparator());`.

I generally prefer the latter as it lets me keep the sorting code separate from the data object that it sorts.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the Student class implements Comparable based on the ID field, use Collections.sort() with the list as single parameter.
2. Otherwise, implement a Comparator that compares the objects using their ID, and use it as second parameter to Collections.sort().